# What is the meaning of auto main()->int?

Tags: c++, c++11

I happened to come across the below code snippet in a video on C++11, where the author uses

```
auto main()->int
```

I didn't understand this. I tried to compile in `g++` using `-std=c++11` and it works.
Can somebody explain to me what is going on here? I tried to search using "auto main()->int" but didn't find any help.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

C++11 introduced a notation for *trailing return types*: If a function declaration is introduced with `auto`, the return type will be specified after the parameters and a `->` sequence. That is, all that does is to declare `main()` to return `int`.

The significance of trailing return types is primarily for function template where it is now possible to use parameters to the function together with `decltype()` to determine the return type. For example:

```
template <typename M, typename N>
auto multiply(M const& m, N const& n) -> decltype(m * n);
```

This declares the function `multiply()` to return the type produced by `m * n`. Putting the use of `decltype()` in front of `multiply()` would be invalid because `m` and `n` are not, yet, declared.

Although it is primarily useful for function template, the same notation can also be used for other function. With C++14 the trailing return type can even be omitted when the function is introduced with `auto` under some conditions.

Comment: and what is the advantage of declaring main this way?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: I'm not claiming that there is an advantage. It is allowed, however, and not worse than the alternative.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm not telling that you say that there's an advantage on the trailing return type (TRT) on `main`, I'm just asking (and wondering) if there's any advantage on this use of the TRT in this context... I think that including this explanation (if any) would be nice to improve the answer

Comment: There's not really an advantage if the return type is `int`, `bool`, `char`, `void`, or a template type shorter than 5 characters.  But it does put every function name starting at the same text column.

Comment: @CTMacUser : Why 5 characters?!

Comment: @P.Windridge : because "auto" is 4 characters long.

Comment: @CTMacUser, ok, yes, but what about the "->"  ?!

Comment: The main advantage if TRT is its [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)-friendliness. For example, If I write a function `template <typename T> auto size(T x) -> decltype(x.size()) {return x.size();}` then it will only participate in overload resolution if `x.size()` is a valid expression. If that is not the case the compiler will search for another overload.

Comment: The only advantage is consistency if someone is using it for everything else. The reason they might use it for everything else is that it puts the name of the function/type/var toward the left and always in the same column. That can be helpful especially when the type or return type are complex.

Comment: In this specific case (when you have no other choice) ... ok, but why would you get a nice looking `int main()` and make it ugly by declaring the type twice `auto main()-> int` . It makes no sense, doesn't improve anything. And people are using it like it's the default thing to do.

Answer (score 22):

This is a uniform function declaration syntax, **trailing return type**, introduced in C++11.

You can't use any other syntax for lamdas, and it's also very convenient for function templates where the result type depends on arguments.

If you want to select *one single syntax* (and I think that's a good idea), then you don't have any choice: the old syntax can't be used for lambdas.

Reason for doing that include:

- Well, a *single* syntax.
- Function name always at the same place visually, supports fast scanning of code.
- Ditto for the result type, easy visual recognition (plus, you don't have to qualify it when it's a type defined in a member function's class).

Reasons against include some added verbosity, use of old compilers that don't understand this syntax, that anything new can feel scary and uncomfortable and just odd.

Comment: +1. I use this syntax even in normal code precisely for this point : *Function name always at the same place visually, supports fast scanning of code*. It is easy for us, humans, to figure out the name of the function with little effort, because just after `auto`, the function-name is written. Visually same for all functions.

Comment: **I personally find `auto main() -> int` a horrible idea.** *"Well, a single syntax."* Except those millions of lines of code that already exist. It will be a mixed syntax with the old codes no matter what. *"Function name always at the same place visually, supports fast scanning of code."* I use the outline generated by my IDE, that's even faster to scan. *"Ditto for the result type, easy visual recognition."* Why is it easier to find out the return type in `auto main() -> int` than in `int main()` where the return type is right up front, I don't have to read through anything to find it out?

Comment: @Ali: re "Why is it easier to find out the return type in auto main() -> int than in int main() where the return type is right up front, I don't have to read through anything to find it out", when you find it necessary to attack a strawman argument you are admitting to having no real argument. Feelings of horror and revulsion are however a legitimate reason to not do something. No matter how irrational the feelings are, they do affect one's actions, and one might be much less productive having to fight them.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Please re-read that question you quoted. Probably my punctuation is unfortunate. The first half ("Why is it easier to find out the return type in `auto main() -> int` than in `int main()`") is the question; I am still waiting for an answer. The second half ("the return type is right up front, I don't have to read through anything to find it out") gives my argument why I find `int main()` easier to read. And let's not forget the outline generated by the IDE which is even faster to scan than the code.

Comment: @Ali: The return type of `main` is not difficult to see at a glance. Your question about this is still a straw-man question. That means that it misrepresents the position you're attacking, and thus is logically invalid as an argument: it's a [well known logical fallacy](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/straw-man.html). Attacking a distorted version of a position simply does not constitute an attack on the position itself.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf *"you're attacking"* I am not attacking anybody / anything. I have left a comment that I disagree and gave my reasons why. You still haven't given me *any* reason why it is easIER to find the return type in `auto main() -> int` than in `int main()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Let me ask you this: Do you think `auto main() -> int` is a good idea? (yes/no) Because as I am reading your answer, it seems to me that you are advocating `auto main() -> int`. That's why we are having this discussion.

Comment: @Ali: I don't see any problem with `auto main() -> int` as notation.

Comment: Passing disinterested observer here. @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't see the strawman. If anything, calling an argument a strawman but then refusing consistently to point out why it is one, seems more of a strawman argument to me than the one being accussed of being one. All I see is you've used the "this is a strawman argument" argument to avoid answering a legit question. I do like the "when you find it necessary to attack a strawman [...]" quote though, even if it doesn't apply here. I wouldn't overuse it to attack non-strawman arguments though, otherwise it loses its strength.

Comment: @Ali He has given reasons why it may or may not be useful in his top answer, and then stated his own personal preference. Your own argument is "well I disagree with this opinion due to my own personal preference". Asking him to "justify" why his personal preference is objectively more useful is a non-sequitur. He has his own personal preference. You have yours. There's no actual arguments or discussion to be had here. Though I will agree that "I see no problem with X" isn't really a good answer for "why do you prefer X".

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: The strawman argument is that the modern notation makes it easier to see the return type of `int main()`. It's a very different proposition from what I've written. Instead of "easy", ali writes "easier", in the sense of always easier, and he changes the context from source code with various functions, to the example of `main`. It's a strawman and it's nonsense. Still, when one chooses modern notation as a single notation, I think it's a good idea to use it also for `main`, i.e. to not make `main` a special case. But I can't see that ali could know that I think so.

Comment: The example of `main` is addressed in the answer's "Reasons against include some added verbosity". I see that as clear enough. I don't think for a second that anyone's been able to misunderstand the text.

Comment: Fair enough, and I agree with your approach. Though I think one would be forgiven for challenging the statement "Reasons for doing that include [...] easy visual recognition for the result type" with "as opposed to what?". I don't think it was meant as misrepresentation. My point is that the argument is more along the lines of "What is better. Red? Or Blue?". There is no objectively "better" way. It's a matter of preference (or local coding standards). If you have reasons to prefer single syntax you'll use auto. If you have reasons not to, you won't. The argument is over nothing of consequence

Comment: Well, the "as opposed to what" for easy visual recognition of return types, includes old syntax used for member function result type that's defined in the class (it then needs to be qualified, with a perhaps long-winded & ugly type specification), and for horribly long template specializations as result type. The former has no solution that I know of with the old syntax, but the latter can be made more quick-code-scan compatible even with the old syntax, just by placing the return type on a separate line before the function name etc. I would love to see some research on this.

Answer (score 12):

It is called *trailing-return-type*. It is particularly useful in generic codes using templates where the return type of depends on the expression involving some other template arguments. It is also used in lambda.

Here is an example:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t+u)
{
   return t + u;
}
```

Here the return type depends on the expression `t+u`. So whatever the type of the expression, is also the return-type of the function, which is indicated by `decltype(t+u)`.

Comment: That was really helpful!