# Can you explain the syntax of this C++ function definition?

Tags: c++

I've seen a function definition in [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519920.aspx) similar to this:

```
auto incr(int i) -> int {return i+1;}
```

It compiles and works fine with VS2012. Can someone explain the syntax of it? Is it a named lambda expression? Where in "The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition" is it described? Why would anyone write it this way, instead of using a simple form:

```
int incr(int i) {return i+1;};
```

Comment: `auto SomeClass::foo() -> SomeInnerClass` allows you to get rid of the `SomeClass::` on the return type. Other than that (except that I forgot the main use, shown in the answer), mainly readability. Anyway, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax).

Comment: It's a new optional synthax added in C++11, it simplifies some things like making namespace implicit, but there is no particular reason to use it. I believe it's main goal is to make code more readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the meaning of auto main()->int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085446/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-main-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a trailing return type. Although it is allowed for all function declarations it is primarily useful when defining function templates. The type returned from function templates often depends on the result of some expressions and it is helpful to have variables of the relevant types around to express them, e.g.

```
template <typename M, typename N>
auto multiply(M const& m, N const& n) -> decltype(m * n) {
    return m * n;
}
```

Since `m` and `n` are only declared after the parameters are declared, putting the return type *after* the parameter declaration rather then *before* helps the template code. In non-template code the use of `auto` may become more useful with C++14 when the return type can be deduced. In C++11 it is essentially a stylistic choice for non-template code.