# Should main with trailing return type be avoided?

Tags: c++, c++11, program-entry-point, c++14

In the code example below the `main` function is written with the C++11 trailing return type notation:

```
auto main() -> int {
  //...
  return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

Are there any reasons that `main` with trailing return type should be avoided and the classical notation should be preferred?

Comment: Interesting question, but is there any practical need for this? I can't think of any downsides but, similarly, can't see any practical use ;-)

Comment: `int main()` being shorter would be one reason to prefer it. Also, (although unrelated) `return 0;` can be left out for `main`.

Comment: Why do you expect this question to [fare any better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418072/pros-and-cons-in-using-trailing-return-type)? My personal opinion on this is that we're all trained to subconsciously pattern match `int main()` as a something innocuous. But whenever I see `auto main() -> int` it causes me to give it a second glance, if only to think *"how silly"*, before moving on.

Comment: Even better `auto main() -> void` JOKE

Comment: @Praetorian The reason is that when I posted a live demo with the new notation, I got criticised by many who were considering that use of trailing return types with no specific reason - or not as part of a specific technique introduces deteriorations. Kindly, I would like  things to be cleared up on this.

Comment: @40two I remember the XML comment from Kerrek :). Obviously, there's nothing *wrong* with it, but it is more keystrokes compared to the old syntax. Use it if that's what you seem fit.

Comment: @Praetorian really no hars feelings with Kerrrek :) I respect the guy pretty much. I really enjoyed the joke :).

Comment: I am pretty sure that "it looks cool" is the only thing this form has going for it. However the value of "it looks cool" should never be underestimated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's perfectly valid and works just fine.

The only issue to concern is that it is new. It may confuse or surprise readers of your code who are only familiar with C++98.

But it works, so feel free to write your `main` this way if you feel like it.

Comment: A possible issue to mention is that some documentation (or static analysis) tools do not support yet the new trailing return type style (they should, as for other new c++ features, indeed)

Answer (score 14):

First, let's see *why* you would want to use trailing return types *in general.*

[Kerrek SB's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418072/pros-and-cons-in-using-trailing-return-type#comment37776499_24418072) to your previous question:

> Trailing return types are a specialized language feature that's mostly
> useful for generic library writers (that is, writers of generic
> libraries, not generic personalities who happen to be writing
> libraries), similar to decltype. Incidentally, both language features
> also have some limited use in obscure or long lambda expressions, but
> they shouldn't be used a lot on "normal" user code.

From [Dietmar Kühl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21085530/341970) (that you have linked in your previous question so you must have read it):

> The significance of trailing return types is primarily for function
> template where it is now possible to use parameters to the function
> together with `decltype()` to determine the return type. For example:
>
> ```
> template <typename M, typename N>
> auto multiply(M const& m, N const& n) -> decltype(m * n);
> ```
>
> This declares the function `multiply()` to return the type produced by `m * n`. Putting the use of `decltype()` in front of `multiply()` would be invalid because `m` and `n` are not, yet, declared.

**I consider both Kerrek SB and Dietmar Kühl C++ experts and find their guidelines good.** Now let's see how the above guidelines apply to `int main()`. Some observations:

- `int main()` is not a function template.
- There is no type deduction going on.
- The return type (`int`) won't change in the foreseeable future; we can safely commit to this type.

> Are there any reasons that main with trailing return type should be avoided and the classical notation should be preferred?

Yes:

1. It confuses those developers who are not familiar with the new
   syntax.
2. Not all tools support this new language feature.
3. As discussed above, using this feature is *unnecessary* with `int main()`.

I rest my case.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to answer. From what I can deduce from your answer, is that using the new notation doesn't introduce any practical deteriorations but the real matter is rather on practical issues like readability of code and developer staff unfamiliarity. Please allow me to consider backward compatibility a none issue since this is the case for almost all of the new features introduced by C++11. P.S I have great respect for both of the gentlemen you mentioned, my sole intention is to learn and I'm learning a lot from them :).

Answer (score 8):

It's plain stupid.

There's no gain, no need or reason to write something like this.

To be pedantic you add the `auto` and `->` symbol for no reason.

A trailing return type is typically used to deduce the return type **after** the function arguments have been introduced. Here you already know the return type.

Can you imagine (the looks of) your code base if all your functions used this notation without the need to do so ? You'd practically keep at the front all the storage, likage specifications, static etc and leave the return type at the end, to mingle with exception specifications, const specifiers and friends ?

---

People you don't need to convince me. **I'm not against trailing return types**; I'm against the "nouveau riche" mentality of using features where there's no need to do it and concerned about **C++ becoming a huge blob of styles and collapsing under its own weight**.

**Lighthearted shifts of the norm** are signs of instabillity and lack of communication. A feature like **Python's [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)** would be a good thing to have and trained eyes should be discarded with caution.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to always use the trailing return type for every function for consistency. Aside from more typing, I can't see any disadvantage.

Comment: "Can you imagine your code base if all your functions used this notation without the need to de so ?" Yes, I can. It's syntactically much closer to how well-designed languages express function types.

Comment: So you'd practically keep at the front all the storage, likage specifications, static etc and leave the return type at the end, to mingle with exception specifications, const specifiers and friends ? Oh what a codebase ...

Comment: "Can you imagine (the looks of) your code base" - I can indeed. It would be slightly more pleasant to read (especially when returning a complex type), but not such a massive improvement that I'd argue about it with those who happen to prefer the old style.

Comment: "to mingle with exception specifications, const specifiers and friends" - the specifiers go before the `->`, and `friend` goes at the beginning ("mingling" with the old-school return type). Nothing "mingles" with the trailing return type.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou I suggest you look at how functions are expressed in mathematics. And in functional programming languages. Or, basically, *everywhere* outside the C family of languages. And I'd love for you to explain *why* it would be such a terrible thing to put the return type at the end. Why is it a bad thing if it "mingles with exception specifications, const specifiers and friends"?

Comment: There was the one argument that your function names line up nicely if it's one per line, too. I think it plays pretty well with C++14 automatic return type deduction syntax as well. In that case, the trailing type is simply left off. [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28e13f6fcb742fb4). Actually, it would be interesting to see this style being discussed at CppCon.

Comment: @jalf my response is in the edit

Comment: In fact, one reason to do it this way is to *reduce* the number of styles/features present in your code by always using trailing return (and makes it easier to switch to C++14 deduction when it arrives)

Comment: You really made your point :), there is no real reason to use a vague expressions to do so though. But I must admit, that your arguments are solid. I'm really concerned about the potential fragmentation of the language too. Doing one thing with many ways can introduce ambiguity which is not a good think. I really think that the community should discuss on the matter.