# Diamonds of triangle in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I just understood the concept of making a triangle in C++ that is made of asterisks. 
    Now that I tried to replace those asterisks by "diamonds of asterisks", I found a very
    logic error and that is the "newline" and I can't find it anymore, can anyone help me
    with my code?
    I want my output to be like a triangle with asterisks, but the asterisks is substituted by asterisks of diamonds.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int number, space1, space2, space3;
int i, j, x, y, z;
cout << "Enter any number: ";
cin >> number;
space1 = (2*number)-1;
space2 = number-1;
space3 = space1*space2;
z = number-1;
for(i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= (2*i)-1; j++){
    for (x = 1; x <= number; x++)
    {
        for(y = 1; y <= space3; y++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(y = 1; y <= number-x; y++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(y = 1; y <= (2*x)-1; y++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        for(y = 1; y <= z; y++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        z--;
        if(x <= number)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    if(z >= 3)
    {
        z = 1;
    }
    for(x = 1; x <= number-1; x++)
    {
        for(y = 1; y <= space3; y++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(y = 1; y <= x; y++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(y = 2*(number-x)-1; y >= 1; y--)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        for(y = 1; y <= z; y++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        z++;
        if(x <= number)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    }
    space3 -= space1;
}
```

}

Comment: *"If a user inputs 2, I want my output to be like this."* - and what is your output like?  How do they differ and where do you suspect it's going wrong?  What can't you manage to fix?  Did you try a debugger?  How are we supposed to understand what you want your code to do for say n 3 or n 4 given no explanation beyond what 2 should be?

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI, C++Builder, or Objective-C++?

Comment: The spaces I made are alright, the only problem I have here is how to remove the newline in every diamond. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you’re really asking (asterisks that are diamonds?) – some example of the desired output could have helped! – but I like this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    for( int y = 0; y < 32; ++y )
    {
        cout << string( 32 - y, ' ' );
        for( int x = 0; x < 32; ++x )
            cout << (x & ~y? ' ' : '*') << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
                               *
                              * *
                             *   *
                            * * * *
                           *       *
                          * *     * *
                         *   *   *   *
                        * * * * * * * *
                       *               *
                      * *             * *
                     *   *           *   *
                    * * * *         * * * *
                   *       *       *       *
                  * *     * *     * *     * *
                 *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
                * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
               *                               *
              * *                             * *
             *   *                           *   *
            * * * *                         * * * *
           *       *                       *       *
          * *     * *                     * *     * *
         *   *   *   *                   *   *   *   *
        * * * * * * * *                 * * * * * * * *
       *               *               *               *
      * *             * *             * *             * *
     *   *           *   *           *   *           *   *
    * * * *         * * * *         * * * *         * * * *
   *       *       *       *       *       *       *       *
  * *     * *     * *     * *     * *     * *     * *     * *
 *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: What's the point of `auto main() -> int` versus `int main()`?

Comment: @immibis: the `auto` syntax was introduced in c++11. it has many advantages.

Comment: I know that. What's the point of using `auto main() -> int` over `int main()`?

Comment: @immibis: you can find that question answered several times here on SO.

Comment: @immibis Here's an answer that explains why people use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085446/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-main-int
In the end it comes down to a style preference

Comment: The spaces I made are alright, the only problem I have here is how to remove the newline in every diamond. Thanks.